Pytorch Style Pseudocode
In more recent scientific papers, the way algorithms are written has become more interesting (personal opinion). How can I implement something similar to the following in LaTeX.


Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Please show the TeX code.

isn't that just python rather than pseudocode, minted or listings have soem python formatting that would b eclose

I am just new with Tex. I tried so many code for it. Anyway, thanks to @egreg and David it is done.

This looks like minted.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[htp]
\caption{Pytorch style pseudocode for OPL}

\begin{minted}{python}
def forward(features, labels):
    """
    features:   features shaped (B, D)
    labels:     targets shaped (B, 1)
    """
    features = F.normalize(features, p=2, dim=1)

    # masks for same and diff class features
    mask = torch.eq(labels, labels.t())
\end{minted}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


You can play with the available styles.
With minted version 3, enabling -shell-escape is no longer needed (but requires two runs of LaTeX, at least when the code is modified or appears for the first time).

Great, thanks a lot.
